# Accessing S3 img from plain javascript while using django storages

Tags: javascript, django

I have a pretty basic issue am unable to solve.
I am serving static files from S3 using Django storages.
In my template, I setup img source like this:

```
"{% static 'fun_share/img/logo/logo.svg' %}"
```

while having

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
```

Django storages handle the actual img src "translation", ie becomes https://my-bucket.amazonaws.com/static/fun_share/img/logo/logo.svg?..... So far so good.

Now, I want to change the image src from plain javascript to I different image (logo-2.svg).

What is the best way to handle calling the s3 bucket with proper URL (also considering secrets and keys)?

I would expect

```
 const logo = document.querySelector(".navbar-brand img");
 logo.src = "/static/fun_share/img/logo/logo-2.svg";
```

to work, but that does not seem to be the case, as the js call is made to the server itself, not redirected to the s3 bucket.

Any help much appriciated.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the current source to a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and then change the `pathname` to get a URL with the same host, query params, etc

```
const logo = document.querySelector(".navbar-brand img");
let sourceUrl = new URL(logo.src)
sourceUrl.pathname = '/static/fun_share/img/logo/logo-2.svg'
logo.src = sourceUrl.toString()
```